# Cases where reflexivity is hard to prove

Tags: soft-question, relations

A couple of remarks at [Surjections and equivalence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476987/surjections-and-equivalence-relations?noredirect=1#comment1027244_476987) lead me to wonder: are there any important and/or interesting examples of reflexive relations whose reflexivity is hard to prove? There are lots of cases where it's pretty trivial:

1. Divisibility: $(\forall x)(x=1\cdot x)$
2. Product ordering: If $(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)$, then $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$, so $x_1 \le_1 y_1$ and $x_2 \le_2 y_2$, so $(x_1,x_2)\preceq(y_1,y_2)$.
3. Modular arithmetic: All positive numbers divide $0$, so every integer is congruent to itself modulo anything.
4. The law of identity immediately proves that the subset relation is reflexive.

I haven't, however, been able to think of a non-contrived, non-trivial example. Contrived: Define a relation $R$ by letting $aRb$ iff the Riemann hypothesis holds.

Comment: If RH is true, then $aRb$ for all $a,b$, and thus $R$ is trivially reflexive; otherwise your relation is $R=\emptyset\subseteq A\times A$, so in particular $R$ is not reflexive.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: thus it is (extremely!) hard to prove whether or not $R$ is reflexive.

Answer (score 3):

See the latter part of Leslie Townes' answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78836/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-a-reflexive-relation/78855#78855).

In particular, note the statement that "it is often the case that reflexivity (when it occurs) is the most difficult property of these three to verify."

Comment: The example looks like it might have some potential, and the points sound valid, but it appears itself to be rather contrived, unless there's some motivation not shown there. I was hoping for a relation that is likely to actually be used for something other than to prove this point.

Comment: @dfeuer In my reading of the answer linked to above, the "example" is not at all contrived. Perhaps I'm not totally clear on what you are looking for.

Comment: A surface satisfying a bunch of constraints whose boundary is the disjoint union of a space homeomorphic to one thing and one homeomorphic to another? How would one come to consider that question?